# Can multiple customers use the same account?

Tags: customer-account

I want to give the employees in the company where I work a fixed 20% discount and special prices on some products.
The problem is that the company has over 40.000 employees, so I can't make an account for everyone. Instead my idea was to make a single account that everyone could use. But is it possible to do it this way?

Some of the problems I ran into was this address book that automatically filled out the shipping information. Furthermore there won't be any email field, when they are logged in, so they wont received an order confirmation, as it would be send to the email the account is registered with. Anyone who have an idea of how to solve this?

Cheers

Comment: Customer groups.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest using customer groups for this...

You could attach an observer to the customer registration process to assign customers with an "@company.com" email address to be automatically assigned to the "Staff" customer group on signup.

--Or---

Provide a "staff only" registration area that does the same.

Comment: Thank your for your answer Matthew. How would you make it "staff only"? Simply be hidding it on the webshop + google and send out the link on the intranet? Maybe the URL should also be very random. Anything else to have in mind? :)

Comment: Depends on your requirements...

You could do a private registration page hidden behind a password or just plain "hidden" from public using robots.txt disallow (which would auto assigned to the staff group), Have staff email in to update their account to the "Staff" level access, pre-setup staff access and send login details in a email campaign.